# How long should it take thousands of records to insert from Bulk API

Tags: bulk-api

I used workbench to insert a mass amount of records, and it said it completed, but nothing is in production. When should I expect them / be concerned if they still aren't there? I understand if it takes a while after it completes, given it's a large data set, but I'd like to know roughly how long before I think something went wrong.

Comment: If you are trying to search for them (using global search) the index could take a while (minutes to hours depending on org and lots of other things). If you are using SOQL or a list view they should be there immediately unless there was an error

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It's thousands of accounts I inserted with a CSV file. It said it did 3 batches, as 1 job, complete, and when I go to "Accounts" in production, there are none

Comment: When you click on the Accounts tab, after seeing the "Recent Item" did you click Go?

Comment: oh wow I feel so stupid. I got so used to seeing a bunch in "Recent" in the sandbox...I forgot to hit go. Well. Thank you!! I'll go hide now. :)

Comment: I update my answer. Please accept if you are inclined to do so. This allows others looking for a similar issue to find answers and rewards both you and I with reputation. The function of the tab / recent items has frustrated almost every user I have ever spoken with.

Comment: That makes me feel better. Thanks, I'll select your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on the Accounts tab, after seeing the "Recent Items" did you click Go?

You can know if something went wrong by reviewing the result of the insert or the file generated as a result of the insert operation. Depending on the tool you may have a success and error file generated

If successful the Id column will be populated. If not the error column will be populated.

If you are trying to search for them (using global search) the index could take a while (minutes to hours depending on org and lots of other things). If you are using SOQL or a list view they should be there immediately unless there was an error